# jQuery-ui stop() animation causing styles to stick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an unordered list with divs in it.  When one is hovered over, the others have a class applied to them that makes them fade out, slightly.

```
<ul class="three_up tiles">
    <li id="ember283" class="ember-view questioncontainer"></li>
    <li id="ember293" class="ember-view questioncontainer"></li>
    <li id="ember298" class="ember-view questioncontainer"></li>
    <li id="ember299" class="ember-view questioncontainer"></li>
    <li id="ember300" class="ember-view questioncontainer"></li>
    <li id="ember301" class="ember-view questioncontainer"></li>
    <li id="ember302" class="ember-view questioncontainer"></li>
</ul>
```

The issue that's occurring is that when a user quickly navigates over them, some will stick with their styling at a certain point.

There's a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QusWU/1/

What should my solution be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use the version of `.addClass` that animates, it does not add the class to the element until the animation finishes. And if the class is not added, then the call to `removeClass` does nothing.

As @ArunPJohny points out, you can use `.stop(true, true)` to jump the animation to the end so the class will get added. That has its own problem though because you don't want the visual effect.

Perhaps you should not use a class and just animate the opacity. That way, it is fine for the animation to stop in the middle and reverse.

```
var $containers = $(".questioncontainer");

$containers.mouseenter(function () {
    var $container = $(this);
    $container.stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
    $container.siblings().stop().animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 500);
});

$containers.mouseleave(function () {
    $containers.stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AuYef/1/)

Comment: That was a thought that I had as well. This is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QusWU/2/.  It works very well.  The other answers were good, and they did technically answer my question.  You had the opportunity to address the flicker.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.stop(true, true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) so that the current animation is ended with the finish value, otherwise the animated properties are left with the values as with that moment.

Look at the `jumpToEnd` parameter of [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$(".questioncontainer").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).siblings().stop(true, true).addClass("nofocus", 500);
});

$(".questioncontainer").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).siblings().stop(true, true).removeClass("nofocus", 500);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cgPt2/)

Comment: First, thank you.  Okay - I actually tried that afterward, I should have mentioned that.  Notice how the other elements kind of flicker, or hope, though?  I'd really like to avoid that.  Do you have any more advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Use `hover()` in Jquery and `ToggleClass` for add and remove Class

```
$(".questioncontainer").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass("nofocus");
});
```

Comment: That actually does the opposite of what I'm looking for - I'd like each `<li>`'s siblings to have the class applied to them.

Comment: @Zaemz. Please try Now

Comment: Thanks Sudharsan - I modified it a little further and tried: `$(this).siblings().stop(true, true).toggleClass("nofocus", 500);`  That actually does what I'm looking for with a slight fade, but the sibling elements flicker quickly, which is the same effect that the other answer is giving me.  I'd like to avoid that.  Thank you, again.